# How to draw a rectangular box(slit) on a region file using python-ds9

Tags: python, ds9

Its my first time to use python code to display ds9 images.I just display  black and white image but I wanted to get a color image with two or more slit positioned on the image  which passes at the center,plus the position angle and coordinates should not be manually typed coz I have many images.I expect something [image] like this.As you see the slits are not at the center I need them all at the center but they are at  different angle.I need your help as usual,thanks!

Comment: What angles should they be at? Do you mean the center of the image or the object being photographed? Please share what cod you have, we really can't recommend anything without it.

Comment: Hi Patrick Haugh, they must be just at the center but the angles are green=5,red=44 and yellow =111.